# Как правильно создать запрос MySQL

Tags: mysql

Две таблици:

- parents: id, name, surname, job;
- students: id, name, surname, gr_id, m_id, f_id;

Необходимо вівести информацию о работе родителей студента Смирнова (использование подзапроса обязательно так как тема "простые подзапроси"). Пробовал так:

```
SELECT * FROM parents WHERE id IN (SELECT m_id, f_id FROM students WHERE surname IN ('Smyrnov')); // здесь пишет операнд должен иметь один столбец

SELECT * FROM parents WHERE id IN (SELECT m_id AND f_id FROM students WHERE surname IN ('Smyrnov')); // понимаю,что поля выборки в подзапросе не перечисляют через "AND", но все же. Получил информацию о матери студента

SELECT * FROM parents WHERE id IN (SELECT m_id FROM students WHERE surname IN ('Smyrnov')) AND (SELECT f_id FROM students WHERE surname IN ('Smyrnov')); // то же, что и в предидущем случае
```

Comment: так какэто правильно сделать?

Comment: Вам надо что бы подзапрос 2 разных поля вернул как отдельные строки. Это обычно делается с помощью UNION

Comment: с UNION делал,но не выело нужный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С под запросом

```
 SELECT * FROM parents 
     WHERE id IN (SELECT m_id FROM students WHERE surname='Smyrnov') 
        OR id IN (SELECT f_id FROM students WHERE surname='Smyrnov');
```

Comment: работает, только не могли бы Ви объяснить, почему с условием "AND" - "empty set"

Comment: @MuscledBoy `select X from tab where id=A and id=B` условие применяется по очереди к каждой записи. И получается что в одной и той же записи id дложно быть равно A _И одновременно_ равно B. А правильное условие id равно A _ИЛИ_ равно B

Comment: @Mike, а ведь действительно все логично. Благодарю за ответ